# Redshift : New table but Group members can't query

Tags: postgresql, security, permissions, amazon-redshift, sql-grant

In Redshift I have a `data_reader` db group defined like this

```
CREATE GROUP data_reader;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA reports TO GROUP data_reader;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA reports TO GROUP data_reader;
```

And I've noticed that whenever I create a new table, group members can't automatically query from the table. They get a `Permission Denied` error. Re-running

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA reports TO GROUP data_reader;
```

Fixes the permission.

Is this just a quirk of Redshift or is there another way I should be defining my db groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement grants access only to already created tables:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA reports TO GROUP data_reader;
```

In order to grant access by default, you must setup default privileges:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA reports TO group data_reader; --Most probably already granted
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA reports GRANT SELECT ON TABLES to group data_reader;
```

Now all new created tables will be granted to group for select.

Answer (score 0):

Any GRANTS you provide are only for the existing tables/views. Anytime a new table is created, you need to explicitly provide the required permissions to users/groups. My suggestion is to probably include the appropriate grants statements in the DDL file.